# Compile-time error using List.addAll to add a List<? extends BaseClass> to another one

Tags: java, generics

In this code, the last line (`list1.addAll(list2);`) generates the compile-time error

> The method addAll(Collection< ? extends capture#3-of ? extends BaseClass>) in the type List< capture#3-of ? extends BaseClass> is not applicable for the arguments (List< capture#4-of ? extends BaseClass>)

I do realize that if this was allowed it would be possible to add to the same list instances of different classes. However I don't know what's the right way to go about this.

My `getList()` method needs to return subclasses of `BaseClass`, I cannot change that requirement.

I have these two lists, declared in the same way and containing the same type of objects, and I need to add one into the other one.
Any thoughts about this would be appreciated.

**BaseClass.java**:

```
package main;

public class BaseClass {}
```

**Main.java**:

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    private static List<? extends BaseClass> getList() {

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<? extends BaseClass> list1 = getList();

        List<? extends BaseClass> list2 = getList();

        list1.addAll(list2); // Compile-time error: "The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#3-of ? extends BaseClass>) in the type List<capture#3-of ? extends BaseClass> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#4-of ? extends BaseClass>)".
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a new `List<BaseClass>` and add both lists to that:

```
List<BaseClass> merged = new ArrayList<>();
merged.addAll(list1);
merged.addAll(lise2);
```

But it might be a better idea to have `getList` return a `List<BaseClass>`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cant determine that the classes are compatible.

In example list1 could be of the type

```
List<SubSubSubClass>
```

and you attempt to merge a BaseClass into it. You cannot Cast BaseClass to a random subclass.
Also:

```
List<? extends BaseClass> list1
```

Will declare a list of objects that are based on BaseClass but the following will do the same:

```
List<BaseClass> list1
```

Try this:

```
 private static List<BaseClass> getList() {

    return new ArrayList<BaseClass>();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<BaseClass> list1 = getList();

    List<BaseClass> list2 = getList();

    list1.addAll(list2);
}
```

This will guarantee that your list items are all of the BaseClass type, or subclasses of this type.

Comment: Good point that `List<BaseClass> list1` will declare a list of objects that are based on `BaseClass` just like my `List<? extends BaseClass> list1` does. However I cannot change the return type of `getList()`, because somewhere else I need to override it and have it return a list of different subclasses of `BaseClass`.